# How to retrieve individual parts of multipart/form-data request body in Apache Camel framework?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

I have defined the following RouteBuilder in Apache Camel framework:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class FilesRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        rest()
                .post("/files/{version}/file-import")
                .id(FilesConstants.REST_FILE_IMPORT_ROUTE)
                .produces("application/zip")
                .consumes("multipart/form-data")
                .route()
                .doTry()
                .to(FilesConstants.FILE_IMPORT)

        String apiEndpoint = RouteUtil.toHttpRoute("https://localhost:8080");

        from(FilesConstants.FILE_IMPORT)
                .id(FilesConstants.FILE_IMPORT)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, constant(String.format("/cust/files/%s/file-import", "v1.56")))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethod.POST))
                .process(exchange -> {
                    FileImportRequest fileImportRequest = exchange.getMessage().getBody(FileImportRequest.class);
                })
                .to(RouteHelper.createToEndpoint(apiEndpoint));

    }
}
```

In RouteBuilder above I am exposing rest api endpoint for files import. This is request body I get:

```
----------------------------894364363213737457457453
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="some_file.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

7;abcdefe;8efsefs4;34
----------------------------894364363213737457457453
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="configuration"
Content-Type: application/json

{"fileTypeId":19}
----------------------------894364363213737457457453--
```

My questions are:

1. How can I modify "configuration" content part in processor block to add another parameter in json body to have something like that:

```
----------------------------894364363213737457457453
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="some_file.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

7;abcdefe;8efsefs4;34
----------------------------894364363213737457457453
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="configuration"
Content-Type: application/json

{"fileTypeId":19, "sample_second_name":"abcdefg"}
----------------------------894364363213737457457453--
```

2. How to assign request body to some entity class?

I have tried to assign request body to FileImportRequest that has following definition:

```
@Value
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FileImportRequest implements Serializable {

        MultipartFile file;

        Configuration configuration;

}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Value
@Data
public class Configuration implements Serializable {

    Long fileTypeId;

}
```

but it returns null value in processor block.